# ViewModel and Model in ASP.NET MVC 3 in regards to DDD - Advice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, domain-driven-design

Going through the tutorial here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/iteration-4-make-the-application-loosely-coupled-cs

I've noticed that they are passing the EF generated entity from the controller to the service layer. Should they be passing the viewmodel instead and then do the mapping in the service layer or is what they are doing correct?

I'm trying to understand the translation of the view model into the actual domain model passed from the service layer to the persistence layer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that lower layers should have no knowledge about the upper levels.

This means that the service layer should have no knowledge of the view models (since they are an implementation detail in the user interface layer)

Comment: Adding to that: the mapping from the EF model to the viewmodel and from the viewmodel to the EF model should be done in the UI layer.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter ...  Use ValueInjector to avoid having to hand-code assignments between UI, domain, and EF objects. EF objects can stay concealed in your repository and inject to domain objects. You can make UI specific objects and bind them between you V & VM and ValueInject them in your application ... but you might consider loosening up the LoD and leak domain objects to the VM only, saving separate UI object maintainence. Horrors!